# Visual Basic 2019 - Click a button programmatically, created by code

Tags: .net, basic

By code, i created a several buttons with the letter of the alphabeth.

```
a = 65
Do
    If a > 90 Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        Dim B As New Button
        Me.Controls.Add(B)
        B.Parent = Me.PanelLetras
        B.Height = 50
        B.Width = 60
        B.Left = B.Left + B.Width + 20
        B.Top = i + 5
        B.Text = Chr(a)
        Buttons.Add(B.Text, B)
        B.Tag = a
        B.Name = Chr(a)
        AddHandler B.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
        B.TabStop = False
        a += 1
    End If
Loop
```

to click on click in one of these buttons i use this, and works fine:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim B As Button = sender
    B.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen
    B.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

But, I want to trigger (**by code**) a click in one of these buttons.
How can i do this? Need help please....

Described in above box

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just call the "Button_Click" event handler, passing the button you want to click to it.

For example, the below would call the click event handler for the 'f' button.

```
a = 65
Do
    If a > 90 Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        Dim B As New Button
        Me.Controls.Add(B)
        B.Parent = Me.PanelLetras
        B.Height = 50
        B.Width = 60
        B.Left = B.Left + B.Width + 20
        B.Top = i + 5
        B.Text = Chr(a)
        Buttons.Add(B.Text, B)
        B.Tag = a
        B.Name = Chr(a)
        AddHandler B.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
        B.TabStop = False
        if b.Text = "f" Then 
            Button_Click(b, new System.EventArgs())
        End If 
        a += 1
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use a `For` loop instead of that wonky do...loop:

```
For a = 65 to 90
    Dim B As New Button
    Me.Controls.Add(B)
    B.Parent = Me.PanelLetras
    B.Height = 50
    B.Width = 60
    B.Left = B.Left + B.Width + 20
    B.Top = i + 5
    B.Text = Chr(a)
    Buttons.Add(B.Text, B)
    B.Tag = a
    B.Name = Chr(a)
    AddHandler B.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    B.TabStop = False
Next
```

It looks like you're storing references to the buttons with:

```
Buttons.Add(B.Text, B)
```

It looks like `Buttons` is a `Dictionary(Of String, Button)`?

If so, you can simply retrieve one of the buttons and call `PerformClick()` against it:

```
Buttons.Item("A").PerformClick()
```